# grunt + compass, I have useless generated files in destination folder

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass

**Gruntfile.js**

In my Gruntfile.js I have following for the watch task:

```
watch: {

        css: {
            files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['compass'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            }
        },
      /* More watched tasks bellow */
    }
```

---

**SASS**

My sass folder has one main file and folder for include files like this:

```
/sass/main.scss
/sass/includes/file.scss
```

---

**CSS**

And when the watch auto generate everything in my destination folders I have:

```
/css/main.css /* it includes everything from the main.scss including all @imports */
/css/includes/file.css /* includes stylesheets from the imported file. But this is useless file and /include/ folder is also an extra, that I do not need. */
```

I suppose it's an issue in the config line:

```
files: ['sass/**/*.scss']
```

but I do not know how to describe to in a way I get only one css folder and one main.css file without extra folders and files

Answer (score 1):

You should change names of your includes files:

```
/sass/includes/file.scss  -> /sass/includes/_file.scss
```

More information you can find here 
:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials